# Android force compress sqlite with jpg extension

Tags: android

I have an old class in an Android app which copies a pre-generated sqlite database. Up to Android 2.3 we needed to change the sqlite extension to an extension which won't be compressed (like jpg as in this question).
As we stop the support for Android prior to 4.1 this is no longer needed.

I want to reduce the apk size, but I want to avoid changing the database's filename. Is there a way to mark the file so it will be compressed when creating the apk although it has the jpg extension?

Comment: Where do you keep this file? Is it in the `assets` folder, in `res/raw` or somewhere else?

Comment: The sqlite file? in the assets folder.

Comment: Can you say what the issue is with changing the filename? Is it coded badly so the name is hardcoded throughout the app or another issue like encryption? This will change the answers which are applicable

Comment: I didn't want to change the filename because it would require differentiation between current users (with the old filename) and new users. I eventually going to keep the same name. I will use a compressible extension in the apk and copy it to the old file name.
Currently this question is for general info for people who might need this kind of info in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which filetypes are not compressed is controlled by the [noCompress](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.html) property :

```
android {

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "txt"
    }

    ....
```

The corresponding aapt option is `-0` :

> -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
>       be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
>       compress any files at all.

Unfortunately it seems that you can either *add* new filetypes to the default list or completely disable compression, but not *remove* a filetype.

So the only solution I can think of would be to do it after the build. For example, with the Linux / Cygwin `zip` and `unzip` :

Extract the file :

```
$ unzip my_app.apk assets/*.jpg
Archive:  my_app.apk
 extracting: assets/some_file.jpg
```

Replace it in the apk, (by default zip always compress) :

```
$ zip -r my_app.apk assets/*
updating: assets/some_file.jpg (deflated 91%)
```

Realign the apk (*before* signing, as we use the new apksigner) :

```
$ zipalign 4 my_app.apk my_app_aligned.apk
```

Sign it :

```
$ apksigner sign --ks my_keystore.keystore -v -out my_app_aligned_signed.apk.apk my_app_aligned.apk
Keystore password for signer #1:
**********
Signed
```

Comment: I would really like to know why this answer was downvoted, it a quite complicated solution (to a quite uncommon problem) but it works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of avoiding to properly change the filename suffix from `jpg` to `db`, it might be better to see if the file with the old one suffix still exists on the device and then rename it accordingly, before opening it - so that the databases of previous versions would seamlessly be migrated (and also, to be able to open it on a computer with the correct handler). just changing the filename will otherwise lead to amnesia due to an inaccessible database file.

`aaptOptions {noCompress "db"}` might be option, but most likely this is not required, unless the file's content would otherwise be corrupted (a smaller package size is ordinary to be preferred).